# Sharepoint 2010, loading webpart type from one sharepoint package (.wsp) solution into another project

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

we have 3 different share point projects in visual studio 2010 containing webparts respective of their category...now we have another webpart project, that dynamically create sub site based on templates.
the problem is that we need to load all webparts and we don't have its type..is there a way to load webpart through reflection or something ...i know we can combine all webparts into one solution, but that will be so messy as then several developer's will be working on one solution.

Any help ..thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defnitely import it through the type. Use the `ImportWebPart` method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartmanager.importwebpart.aspx